# About warn "Dispatcher has no subscribers"

Tags: spring-integration

I want use PublishSubscribeAmqpChannel to send message to other system by rabbitmq, And my system needn't consume this message. When I do this, I always get the warn "Dispatcher has no subscribers for amqp-channel 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". I want know is normal? And I want know how can I make this not show in my log without change log level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PublishSubscribeAmqpChannel` comes with the logic like this:

```
protected AbstractDispatcher createDispatcher() {
    BroadcastingDispatcher broadcastingDispatcher = new BroadcastingDispatcher(true);
```

where that `true` means:

```
public BroadcastingDispatcher(boolean requireSubscribers) {
```

and then further in the logic:

```
public boolean dispatch(Message<?> message) {
    int dispatched = 0;
    int sequenceNumber = 1;
    Collection<MessageHandler> handlers = this.getHandlers();
    if (this.requireSubscribers && handlers.size() == 0) {
        throw new MessageDispatchingException(message, "Dispatcher has no subscribers");
    }
```

So, that means this kind of message channels cannot go without any subscribers to consumer sent messages. This feels suspicious since I definitely may have a logic when one of the nodes in the cluster comes without any consumers, meanwhile all the node can send to this channel. We may reconsider this logic. Feel free to raise an issue on Github, so we will have some team discussion.

Nevertheless this logic doesn't look like a problem for your requirements. What you say about send-n-forget is not a correct way to use `MessageChannel` abstraction. What is the problem for you to use a regular `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` as an outbound channel adapter?

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-outbound-channel-adapter

Comment: thank you for your reply. Now I know why had this warn. I understand the reason for this design and got a solution.